# rdata field of a DNS-SD PTR packet sent via scapy results in an unknown extended label in wireshark

Tags: dns, wireshark, scapy

Currently I'm trying to mock a DNS-SD reply for a query that asked for _printer._tcp.local

What I'm sending with scapy is the following:

```
send(IP(dst="224.0.0.251")/UDP(sport=5353,dport=5353)/DNS(aa=1, qr=1,rd=0,an=DNSRR(rrname='_printer._tcp.local', type="PTR", rclass=1, ttl=100, rdata="Devon's awesome printer._printer._tcp.local")))
```

However, when I check in Wireshark I get the following erroneous packet

```
_printer._tcp.local: type PTR, class IN, <Unknown extended label>
```

I assume I'm having some wrong parameters in my send function. However, I tried some variations and I can't seem to get it to work properly (I compared with an actual reply from a printer and to me it looks the same).

Could anyone help me out with the correct parameters? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an outstanding issue as can be seen on [scapy's issue tracker](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/issue/303/unknown-extended-label-creating-a-custom).

Therefore, you have to encode the `rdata` field yourself, as follows:

```py
from scapy.all import *
import struct

label = "Devon's awesome printer._printer._tcp.local"
sublabels = label.split(".") + [""]
label_format = ""

for s in sublabels:
    label_format = '%s%dp' % (label_format, len(s) + 1)
    
label_data = struct.pack(label_format, *sublabels)  # see edit for Python 3 below

send(IP(dst="224.0.0.251")/UDP(sport=5353,dport=5353)/DNS(aa=1,qr=1,rd=0,an=DNSRR(rrname='_printer._tcp.local',type="PTR",rclass=1,ttl=100,rdata=label_data)))
```

**EDIT for Python 3:**

```py
from scapy.all import *
import struct

label = "Devon's awesome printer._printer._tcp.local"
sublabels = label.split(".") + [""]
label_format = ""

for s in sublabels:
    label_format = '%s%dp' % (label_format, len(s) + 1)
    
label_data = struct.pack(label_format, *(bytes(s, encoding="ascii") for s in sublabels))  # this line was edited for Python 3

send(IP(dst="224.0.0.251")/UDP(sport=5353,dport=5353)/DNS(aa=1,qr=1,rd=0,an=DNSRR(rrname='_printer._tcp.local',type="PTR",rclass=1,ttl=100,rdata=label_data)))
```

Comment: Running this gives me the following error `struct.error: argument for 'p' must be a bytes object`. How to re-factor this for python3 `'%s%dp'` ?

Comment: I updated my answer to support _Python 3_.